flutter modal bottom sheet library scroll problem

When using a modal bottom sheet that expands to full screen height, there's an inconsistency in the scrolling behavior. Specifically, when the user attempts to dismiss the sheet by pulling it down, the content within the sheet scrolls faster than the sheet itself. This creates a disjointed user experience where the content appears to "fall out" of the bottom sheet container.
Steps to Reproduce
Implement a modal bottom sheet.
Set the sheet to expand to full screen height.
Include scrollable content within the sheet (e.g., a or ).ListViewSingleChildScrollView
Open the bottom sheet so it covers the full screen.
Attempt to dismiss the sheet by pulling down from the top.
Actual Behavior
As the user pulls down, the content inside the sheet scrolls faster than the sheet itself, creating a visual disconnect between the sheet's movement and its content.
org issue
[ https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet/issues/431 ]
When pulling down to dismiss the sheet, the entire sheet (including its content) should move down uniformly, maintaining the relative position of the content within the sheet.
